mi menu me arrastra el contenido <php
abro el menu todo lo mas bien pero al cerrarlo dicho menu me arrastra el contenido php, esta parte = <?php $directory="./galeria/imagenes/";, aclaro todas las imagenes del centro las manda para el lado izquierdo al abrirlo de nuevo las pone en su lugar pero lo vuelvo a cerrar y las vuelve a correr, solo me pasa en el celular al cambiar el formato del menu, desde la computadora ningun problema pero al achicarse el menu para otros dispositivos me pasa esto y no se que hacer, soy mas o menos nuevo en todo esto y quisiera encontrar alguna solucion?


bootstrap.min2 enlace
style enlace
<html oncontextmenu="return false;" class="noselect" ondragstart="return false;" ondrop="return false;" align="center">
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Bri Tarot Y Velomancias</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="imagenes/tarot.png">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <script src="js/jquery-latest.js"></script>
        <script src="js/menu.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min2.css">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <center>
    <table border="0">
  <tbody>
      <tr>
      <td align="center"><img src="imagenes/banner.png" width="70%" height="70%" alt=""/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
    <header>
            <div class="menu_bar"> <a href="#" class="bt-menu"><span class="icon-menu"></span>Menu</a> </div>
            <nav>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="index.php"><span class="icon-home"></span>Inicio</a></li>
                  <li class="submenu">
                    <a href="#"><span class="icon-price-tags"></span>Tienda<span class="caret icon-arrow-down6"></span></a>
                    <ul class="children">
                        <li><a href="lecturas.php">Lectuas<span class="icon-dot"></span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="velas.php">Velas<span class="icon-dot"></span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="velones.php">Velones<span class="icon-dot"></span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="rituales.php">Rituales<span class="icon-dot"></span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="otros.php">Otros<span class="icon-dot"></span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                  <li class="submenu">
                    <a href="#"><span class="icon-film"></span>Referencias<span class="caret icon-arrow-down6"></span></a>
                    <ul class="children">
                        <li><a href="imagenes.php">Imagenes<span class="icon-dot"></span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="audios.php">Audios<span class="icon-dot"></span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="contactos.php"><span class="icon-address-book"></span>Contactos</a></li>
              </ul>
            </nav>
          </header>
    <section class="home">
        <div class="in-flex">
            <nav class="card-columns" style="margin: auto">
            <?php
    $directory="./galeria/imagenes/";
    $dirint = dir($directory);
    while (($archivo = $dirint->read()) !== false)
    {
        if (eregi("gif", $archivo) || eregi("jpg", $archivo) || eregi("png", $archivo) || eregi("jpeg", $archivo)){
            echo '<nav class="card">';
            echo '<a href="'.$directory."/".$archivo.'" data-lightbox="models">'."\n";
            echo '<img src="'.$directory."/".$archivo.'" class="card-img-top" alt="...">'."\n";
            echo '</a>';
            echo '</nav>';
        }
    }
    $dirint->close();
?>  
    </nav>
        </div>
        <div class="in-flex">
            <div>
         <span class="parpadea oferta">Promociones:</span><br>
<br>
<span class="promos">2 Velas A Eleccion $8.000 (No Incluye AbreCaminos)</span><a class="add_to_cart_button2" href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=+5492364338738&text=Hola%20Bri,%20Me%20Interesa%20La%20Promo%20De%202%20Velas" target="_blank"><i class="icon-whatsapp">Pedir</i></a><br><br>
<span class="promos">Vela De Descarga + Vela De Limpieza + Vela De Proteccion $12.000</span><a class="add_to_cart_button2" href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=+5492364338738&text=Hola%20Bri,%20Me%20Interesa%20La%20Promo%20De%20Descarga,%20Limpieza%20Y%20Proteccion" target="_blank"><i class="icon-whatsapp">Pedir</i></a><br><br>
<span class="promos">2 Velas De Limpieza + Ritual De Amor $16.000</span><a class="add_to_cart_button2" href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=+5492364338738&text=Hola%20Bri,%20Me%20Interesa%20La%20Promo%20De%202%20Velas%20De%20Limpieza%20+%20El%20Ritual%20De%20Amor" target="_blank"><i class="icon-whatsapp">Pedir</i></a><br><br>
<span class="promos">Limpieza Del Hogar + Velon AbreCaminos 7 Dias 7 Noches $60.000</span><a class="add_to_cart_button2" href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=+5492364338738&text=Hola%20Bri,%20Me%20Interesa%20La%20Promo%20De%20Limpieza%20Del%20Hogar%20+%20Velon%207%20Dias%207%20Noches%20AbreCaminos" target="_blank"><i class="icon-whatsapp">Pedir</i></a><br><br></div>
          <div> <a href="https://www.tiktok.com/@briisaa.2024" target="_blank">
                  <img class="redes" src="imagenes/tiktok.png" width="30%" alt=""/></a><br>
                <a href="https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=61566286536931&mibextid=ZbWKwL/" target="_blank"><img class="redes" src="imagenes/face.png" width="20%" alt=""/></a>
                <a href="https://www.instagram.com/bri_tarotoficial/" target="_blank">
                    <img class="redes" src="imagenes/insta.png" width="20%" alt=""/></a>
              </div>
        </div>
    </section></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</center>
<a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=+5492364338738&text=Hola%20Bri,%20Tengo%20Una%20Consulta" target="_blank"><img class="btn-flotante" src="imagenes/wp.png" width="5%" height="9%" alt=""/></a>
<center>
  <FONT SIZE=2 COLOR="gray">© copyright todos los derechos reservados (Alejandro Dominguez 2024)</FONT>
</center>
<script src="js/lightbox-plus-jquery.min.js" ></script>
</body>
</html>


¿Y cuál es tu código CSS3?

bootstrap.min2 enlace
style enlace
